# How to make a timer using React.js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am using React Hooks to make a counter using React. Unfortunately, the counter doesn't seem to work. It is behaving most haphazardly:

1.) behaving async (updating now and then without following my **setInterval()** function)

2.) not obeying a clear `if` logic.

3.) and sometimes it is counting twice

carousel.js

```
export default function Carousel(props) {
  // setState is async

  let [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  let counter = () => {
    while (count < 4) {
      if (count === 3) {
        setCount(0);
      }
      setCount(count + 1);
    }
  };

  setInterval(counter, 1000);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Everytime your `Carousel` function is ran (which is everytime react recalculates something) It's going to start another timer

Comment: Logic like this should probably be contained within a `useEffect` as to not run into this issue

Comment: Also, you're setting `count` to 0 then immediately adding 1 to it in the `setCount(count + 1)` - make sure that's what you want

Comment: bro what resources did you use to learn react hooks? i am really struggling. can you please share your learning exprerience?

Comment: I typically just refer to the react docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside comments, I also think your count state is kept its first value as when counter is fired.
You could use `setState((prevState, props) => prevState + 1)` or a `useRef()` to keep trace of it.
I suggest to learn on https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify an empty array as second argument of your useEffect so it only fires once. Here everytime your component rerenders, it will execute the function again, that is why it sometimes count 2.

```
useEffect(() => myFunction(), [])
```

The second argument (the array) is all the variables you want to watch so everytime one of them changes, the callback inside the useEffect executes. By passing an empty array you dont watch any variables so it only fires once.

Comment: bro how did you learn so much about react? i am really struggling. can you please share your learning exprerience?